# Optimization over a complex unit circle

Tags: calculus, matrices, complex-analysis, optimization, matrix-decomposition

I have a problem in the following form:

$\underset{\mathbf{x}}{\text{min}} \mathbf{||Ax - b||^2_2}$

s.t $|[\mathbf{x}]_n| = 1; \forall n$

$\mathbf{A}$ is a complex $M \times N$ matrix and $\mathbf{x}$ and $\mathbf{b}$ is a $N \times 1$ vector. The problem is non-convex due to the constraint which says that each element of the complex vector $\mathbf{x}$ has unit modulus, i.e, a complex unit circle.

Hence, its difficult to find any closed form solution for the above problem. Can anyone kindly suggest any feasible optimization technique to solve the above problem.

Comment: Make $x_k = e^{i\phi_k}$ so the problem now has no restrictions.

Comment: Local or global?

Comment: I don't think there is a general closed-form solution. You can just relax the problem, take the dual to upper bound the problem. Or, you can penalize the constraint in the objective function to approach the solution. I am not 100% sure, so not posting this as an answer.

Comment: The objective is convex so relaxing the constraint may give global optimal. But I am also looking for an approximate local solution incase the constraint is not relaxed.

Comment: Even if you make the transformation, you have to put constraints on $\phi$ to be between 0 and $2\pi$. Also, is there a constraint on whether $A^HA$ is positive definite?

Comment: No there is no such constraint on A.

Comment: http://www1.se.cuhk.edu.hk/~manchoso/papers/cqp-ipco05.pdf

Comment: In the paper www1.se.cuhk.edu.hk/~manchoso/papers/cqp-ipco05.pdf, the optimization is for $z^H Q z$, whereas the above problem will give: $z^H Q z  - 2Re\{z^H a\}$. Can $z^H Q z  - 2Re\{z^H a\}$ be reduced to $z^H Q z$?